# vuejs component event with : not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

I have a vuejs component, inside one method of my components, I am dispatching an event like this:

```
this.$emit('user:registerd', [user])
```

On the parent I try to capture it using

```
<user v-on:user:registered="showSuccess"> </user>
```

But the above never runs `showSuccess` method. If I leave out the `:` part from the emit and v-on everything works just fine. I thought it was possible to use `:` to somehow use it in components.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: you have a typo here: `$emit('user:register[e is missing]d',`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you emit:

```
this.$emit('user:registerd', [user])
```

Listen to:

```
<user v-on:user:registerd="showSuccess"> </user>
```

OTOH, if you want to listen to:

```
<user v-on:user:registered="showSuccess"> </user>
```

You should emit like:

```
this.$emit('user:registered', [user])
```

Just keep in mind you are sending an one-element array into the handler function.

Small demo:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('user:registered', [123])">CLICK ME TO EMIT EVENT</button>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
   showSuccess(e) {
      this.message = 'Success. Received: ' + JSON.stringify(e);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <child @user:registered="showSuccess"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the difference between the code. Can you explain the difference? For me, it's same as OP has.

Comment: He's emitting an event with a name and listening to a different name. I thought `:` had something to do with it, but, as I tested in the small demo, it actually didn't.

Comment: Ah, I'm dumb... still can't see the diff.

Comment: Check the name actually in `$emit(eventName)` and the one the OP listens to `v-on:eventName`.

Comment: Yeah, i can't believe I had a typo

Comment: Oh, there was a typo. :)